# SQL Sum QTY Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this sample table:

```
Product    |   Category    |    QTY      |   Load Date
-----------+---------------+-------------+--------------
   1            Alpha           10         Jan. 1, 2021
   2            Beta            20         Jan. 1, 2021
   3           Charlie          20         Jan. 1, 2021
   1            Alpha           30         Jan. 2, 2021
   3           Charlie          30         Jan. 3, 2021
   1            Alpha          -50         Jan. 4, 2021
   2            Beta           -20         Jan. 4, 2021
   4            Delta           40         Jan. 4, 2021
```

I want to add a column that will sum the quantity base on Previous Load Date, and group by Product and Category.

How can I come up with an output as shown below?

```
Product    |   Category    |    QTY      |   Load Date   |  Sum_QTY
-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------
   1            Alpha           10         Jan. 1, 2021       10
   2            Beta            20         Jan. 1, 2021       20
   3           Charlie          20         Jan. 1, 2021       20
   1            Alpha           30         Jan. 2, 2021       40
   3           Charlie          30         Jan. 3, 2021       50
   1            Alpha          -50         Jan. 4, 2021      -10
   2            Beta           -20         Jan. 4, 2021        0
   4            Delta           40         Jan. 4, 2021       40
```

Your help means a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading the question correctly, using [SUM as an analytic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will make the query fairly straight forward;

```
SELECT *,
 SUM("QTY") OVER (PARTITION BY "Product", "Category" ORDER BY "Load Date") Sum_QTY
FROM Table1
ORDER BY "Load Date", "Product", "Category"
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f58b85/1)

Comment: I think its better use [Load Date] instead if "Load Date" . . .

Comment: @zambee Is there a difference except using `" "` being portable(ish) between DBMS's and `[ ]` being SQL Server specific? (honest question, if there is a difference, I don't know about it)

Comment: Hello Mr.  @Joachim Isaksson  I think [] is better. because in Dynamic SQL "" It can create big problems for development and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using an outer apply

```
select t.*, 
       s.sum_QTY
from   Table1 t
  outer apply ( select sum(t2.QTY) sum_QTY from Table1 t2 where t2.Category = t.Category and t2.[Load Date] <= t.[Load Date] ) s
ORDER BY [Load Date], Product, Category
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f58b85/11)